# Mail doesn't arrive at specific recipient

Tags: php

I am sending mails to multiple recipients with php mail like so

```
/*... Something else before that */
  $from = 'machine domain <machine@differentdomain.com>>';
  $sendTo = 'Recipient 1 <recipient@differentdomain.com>';
  $sendTo .= ', Someone <someone@gmail.com>';
  $sendTo .= ', Somebody else <somebody@domain.com>';

  $subject = "Some text";
  $emailText = "Some other text";
  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
      'From: ' . $from,
      'Reply-To: ' . $from,
      'Return-Path: ' . $from,
  );

  mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

  header("Location: "page_new.html");
  die();
  }
}
```

While the mail does arrive correctly at the last 2 recipients, it does never arrive at the first one.

All 3 recipients do have different domains and are not the same as the senders' address. All 3 recipients do work correctly as they do receive messages all the time. And no: It's not in the spam-folder.

What else could I do? How could I debug?

Comment: You have an extra `>` on the first address.